# What does "__consuming" do in Swift?

Tags: swift

There are functions prepended with `__consuming` in [Sequence.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift) (most likely other places too, but I haven't really looked around). I know it's some type of declaration modifier but I'm not sure what it does.

Comment: See https://forums.swift.org/t/preparing-the-iteration-abi-for-move-only-types/12980.

Comment: So it was added as a marker on Sequence and Collection functions to indicate that they will eventually support move-only types?

Comment: That's how I understand it, but I am not an expert on this topic.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As I understand it, `__consuming` doesn't actually do anything yet. It has been added in anticipation of the implementation of [move-only types](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/OwnershipManifesto.md#non-copyable-types), at which point it will be used to in order to denote a method that *consumes* the value it is called upon (i.e the value will be moved from the caller to the callee).

To illustrate, consider this pseudocode:

```
// Foo is a move-only type, it cannot be copied.
moveonly struct Foo {
  consuming func bar() { // Method is marked consuming, therefore `self` is moved into it.
    print(self) // We now 'own' `self`, and it will be deinitialised at the end of the call.
  }
}

let f = Foo()
f.bar() // `bar` is a `consuming` method, so `f` is moved from the caller to the callee.
print(f) // Invalid, because we no longer own `f`.
```

The attribute is currently prefixed by two underscores in order to indicate that it shouldn't be used by users until move-only types are actually implemented, at which point it will likely be renamed to `consuming`.

As you've found out, some standard library protocol requirements [have been marked `__consuming`](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/16894) in order to indicate that they can be satisfied by a consuming method of a move-only type, as well as a non-consuming method. This is in much the same way that a `mutating` protocol requirement indicates that it can be satisfied by a `mutating` method on a value-type, or an otherwise non-mutating method (but as far as I'm aware, no actual compiler logic backs the checking of `__consuming` yet).

For example, the `filter(_:)` requirement on `Sequence` has been marked consuming, as an adopting sequence of move-only elements would need to be able to move the applicable elements into the resulting array, thereby invalidating the sequence.

The reason why the attribute has been added well before the implementation of move-only types is in preparation for the Swift 5 ABI stability freeze. [As Martin says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51292799/what-does-consuming-do-in-swift#comment89563468_51292799), this is discussed in more detail on the forums:

- [Preparing the iteration ABI for move-only types](https://forums.swift.org/t/preparing-the-iteration-abi-for-move-only-types/12980)

Answer (score 4):

It's an [attribute](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Attributes.html) defined by a macro in [Attr.def](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/include/swift/AST/Attr.def):

```
CONTEXTUAL_SIMPLE_DECL_ATTR(__consuming, Consuming,
  OnFunc | OnAccessor |
  DeclModifier |
  UserInaccessible |
NotSerialized, 40)
```